# ¿Cómo copiar propiedades de un elemento a otro en java netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

quisiera saber si existe la manera de copiar las propiedades de un elemento de java como un jtable, JLabel o JText a otros elementos del mismo tipo, esto con el objetivo de ahorrar tiempo a la hora de cambiar el diseño de mis formularios

Todas estas propiedades son las que quiero copiar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué propiedades en específico?

Comment: Color, tamaño, tipo de letra, alto de las columnas de una tabla, background

Comment: ok, entonces actualmente que "Color, tamaño, tipo de letra, alto de las columnas de una tabla, background " tienes?

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans tiene un metodo llamado initcomponent que se logra ver en el constructor. Mas abajo esta la inicializacion.

```
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
 //Todo el codigo se obvio por simplicidad.

}// </editor-fold>
```

Lo que puedes hacer es tomar esta inicializacion y copiarlo en otras JFrame en su constructor.

Comment: ¿O sea que creo las propiedades por codigo y despues copio las líneas? yo pensaba en alguna opcion que me lo hiciera por grafico para no escribir mas lineas de código, pero si es una buena opción

Comment: EL detalle para ese caso seria ver como acceder al formulario que auto genera esto en netbeans y buscar la manera de copiarlo pero habría que investigar mas.